# Limit of the given expression.

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

For $x>0$,$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\big(\sin(x)\big)^{\frac{1}{x}}+\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big)^{\sin(x)}\right]$$ is?. So now I calculated limits individually. Let $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(x)^{1/x}=y$ thus I took log to get
$$
\frac{1}{x}\big(1-(1-\sin(x))\ldots\big)=1
$$ (after writing $\sin(x)=1-(1-\sin(x))$ and then using series expansion for $\ln(1-x)$. So I got it as $1$ thus $y=e$ and similarly for next I got limit value as $1$ thus the value of limit is $e+1$ but correct answer given is $1$ . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$A=\sqrt[x]{\sin (x)}\implies \log(A)=\frac 1x \log (\sin (x))$$ Now, using Taylor expansion $$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)=x\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)$$ $$\log (\sin (x))=\log (x)+\log\left(1-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)\right)=\log (x)-\frac{x^2}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\log(A)=\frac 1x \log (\sin (x))=\frac{\log (x)}{x}-\frac{x}{6}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ So,$\log(A)\to -\infty$ that is to say $A\to 0$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
-\sin x\cdot \log x= -\frac{\sin x}x \cdot x\log x\to -1 \cdot 0= 0
$$ giving

> $$
> \left(\frac1x \right)^{\large \sin x}=e^{-\sin x\cdot \ln x} \to e^0=1
> $$

and, as $x \to 0^+$,
$$
\frac{\log(\sin x)}x =\frac1x \cdot\log(\sin x)\to \infty \times (-\infty) =-\infty
$$ giving

> $$
> \left(\sin x \right)^{\large \frac1x}=e^{\large \frac{\log(\sin x)}x } \to e^{-\infty}=0
> $$

Thus the sought limit is equal to $1$.